# How Linq and Lambda works

Tags: c#

How does lambda expression works internally and what is the role of Expression tree?

Also how linq gets expanded to lambda and heceforth to expression tree?

... it has been asked in an interview

If anyone knows, please share....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking two things:

- What are expression trees; what's the purpose of them?
- How are "query expressions" translated by the C# compiler?

If that's the case, then my Edulinq blog posts will probably help:

- [Part 43: IQueryable](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/20/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-43-out-of-process-queries-with-iqueryable.aspx)
- [Part 41: How query expressions work](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx)

In summary:

- Expression trees are *data* representations of lambda expressions (typically; you can construct them yourself as well), so they can be analyzed by code like LINQ to SQL, and converted into SQL. Lambda expressions can also be converted into delegate instances, which are just like any other delegate instances - basically you can *execute* them, but not really find out the details of the logic inside them.
- Query expressions are translated in a fairly simple way, translating "C# with query expressions" into "C# without query expressions" which is then compiled as normal. So for example a query of:

  ```
  from person in people
  where person.Age > 18
  select person.Name
  ```

  is translated to

  ```
  people.Where(person => person.Age > 18)
        .Select(person => person.Name)
  ```

Comment: You should also differentiate in your answer between lambda expressions that are compiled delegates vs lambda expressions that are actually instances of a LambdaExpression expression tree (uncompiled).

Comment: @JeffN825: Have added in that lambda expressions can also be converted to delegates.

Comment: Sir that is fine.. also it will be great if you explain how lambda works

Comment: @wanttolearn: "how lambda works" is a pretty vague question. What exactly do you mean, and how much research have you already done? If you do a search for "lambda expression C#" you'll get a *lot* of hits...

Answer (score 0):

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.

You can read about it with examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Two other good introductions to C# lambda expressions:

- [Explaining C# lambda statements in one sentence (and LINQ in about 10)](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/04/explaining-c-lambda-statements-in-one-sentence-and-linq-in-about-10.html)
- [LINQ in Action](http://linqinaction.net/)

The first (disclaimer - my blog) will give you a quick explanation of the fundamental concepts. The book provides complete coverage of all relevant topics.